# SQL Using PARTITION when comparing values in consecutive DataRows

Tags: sql

I'm using a SQL statement to compare consecutive values of a field [Allocation] as follows:

```
;WITH cteMain AS
(SELECT AllocID, CaseNo, FeeEarner, Allocation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AllocID) AS sn
FROM tblAllocations)

SELECT m.AllocID, m.CaseNo, m.FeeEarner, m.Allocation, 
       ISNULL(sLag.Allocation, 0) AS prevAllocation,
      (m.Allocation - ISNULL(sLag.Allocation, 0)) AS movement
FROM cteMain AS m

LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLag
ON sLag.sn = m.sn-1;
```

The query returns a calculated field [movement] which is the increase or decrease in consecutive values of [Allocation].

I have included a screen shot of the data returned by this query.

[image: Screenshot of returned data]

However the query is not yet complete.  I need to revise the statement so that the consecutive values of [Allocation] compared are grouped / partitioned by [FeeEarner] and [CaseNo].

For example, at line 18 of the data, the [Allocation] is 800 and is compared to a previous value of 600.  But the previous value belongs to a different [CaseNo] i.e. 6 rather than 31.  In fact [FeeEarner] 'PJW' has no previous [Allocation] on [CaseNo] '31' and so the [prevAllocation] should be '0' from the ISNULL keyword.

I have tried changing

```
OVER (ORDER BY AllocID)
```

to

```
OVER (PARTITION BY CaseNo, FeeEarner ORDER BY AllocID)
```

But that results in a lot of lines of data being repeated.

Can someone advise how to compare consecutive values of [Allocation] but only between rows of data with matching [FeeEarner] AND [CaseNo] please?

**NOTE** - I cannot use LAG because my customer is using SQL Server 2008 R2 which does not support Parallel Data Warehousing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you were close. Try this (notice the added pieces in the join clause to match the partition - without this you will match every row number 3 with every row number 2 *across partitions*, which is what you were seeing):

```
;WITH cteMain AS
(
    SELECT AllocID, CaseNo, FeeEarner, Allocation, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseNo, FeeEarner ORDER BY AllocID) AS sn
    FROM tblAllocations
)    
SELECT m.AllocID, m.CaseNo, m.FeeEarner, m.Allocation, 
       ISNULL(sLag.Allocation, 0) AS prevAllocation,
      (m.Allocation - ISNULL(sLag.Allocation, 0)) AS movement
FROM cteMain AS m

LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLag
    ON sLag.CaseNo = m.CaseNo
    AND sLag.FeeEarner = m.FeeEarner
    AND sLag.sn = m.sn-1
```

Comment: Awesome - tyvm for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your join condition as well:

```
FROM cteMain m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     cteMain sLag
     ON sLag.sn = m.sn-1 and sLag.FeeEarner = m.FeeEarner and slag.CaseNo = m.CaseNo
```

Also, you should have only one `order by` in the `row_number()` call.

Also, if you are using Oracle, SQL Server 2012, newer versions of DB2, or Postgres, then the `lead()`/`lag()` functions would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with OUTER APPLY and EXISTS

```
SELECT t1.AllocID, t1.CaseNo, t1.FreeEarner, t1.Allocation, 
       ISNULL(o.Allocation, 0) AS PrevAllocation, 
       (t1.Allocation - ISNULL(o.Allocation, 0)) AS movement
FROM tblAllocations t1 
OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT t2.AllocID, t2.CaseNo, t2.FreeEarner, t2.Allocation
             FROM tblAllocations t2
             WHERE EXISTS (
                           SELECT 1
                           FROM tblAllocations t3
                           WHERE t1.AllocID > t3.AllocID
                           HAVING MAX(t3.AllocID) = t2.AllocID
                           ) AND t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo
             ) o
```